# Facebook Login fetch error. "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, authentication, native

I am trying to get the data that I receive from facebook login to my backend server but I got stuck at debbuging this error and I can't seem to figure it out.

Would be lovely of someone could help me out, thanks in advance.

This is my button function:

```
 facebookSignin() {
    FBLoginManager.loginWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email'], (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      let profile;
      try {
        profile = JSON.parse(data.profile);
        console.log(data.profile);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      /* signin on server with token */
      return fetch(`http://${this.serverHost}/users/signin/provider`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        body: JSON.stringify({
          provider: 'facebook',
          id: profile.id,
          email: profile.email,
          name: profile.name,
          token: data.credentials.token
        })
      })
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
          /* get user data and auth token from server */
          console.log(data);
        });
    });
  }
```

and i get the error:

"Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Comment: are you getting data in console.log(data.profile);

Answer (score 1):

You parsing data in `try` block but trying to get access to `person` data outside it.

If you'll get an error by `JSON.parse` you variable `persons` will be still `undefined`. And when you'll try to read `id` prop of it you'll get the error `"Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"`.

Put your `fetch` code block inside `try` after `JSON.parse`;

Comment: Indeed, and you can catch this error by catching the promise by adding a `catch` after your last `then`, like `.then(data => {console.log(data);}).catch(error => {console.error(error)});`